# Parse Error on PHP i.e. T_STRING on my php 5.6 server

Tags: php

I got the Parse error when i try to run following PHP code.
I got the error is i.e.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'laptop' (T_STRING) in 
    /home/u111963560/public_html/JSON2/DbOperation.php on line 23

```
<?php

class DbOperation
{
private $con;

function __construct()
{
    require_once 'DbConnect.php';
    $db =new DbConnect();
    $this->con = $db->connect();
}


public function getLaptops(){

    if($statement=$con->prepare(“SELECT * FROM laptop LIMIT 1”)){


        // Execute
        $statement-> execute();

        // Close statement
        $statement-> close();
}

// Close entire connection
$conn-> close();
    }

}
```

Comment: “” - those aren't PHP quotes. Don't copy and paste things from badly formatted tutorials.

Comment: Hey look, "smart quotes" around your SQL query. Don't edit code in MS Word.

Comment: Thank you so much, i knew where i am wrong.